# label doesn't update on older system version - xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have issue.

Label doesn't update on older version. 
On android system version 8.1 everything is ok but for instance on 7.1 version refreshing label doesn't work.

```
  private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var lab_seconds = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView_seconds);
            lab_seconds.Text = (Int32.Parse(lab_seconds.Text) -1).ToString();
            lab_seconds.RefreshDrawableState();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your timer callback is not on the UI thread:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        var lab_seconds = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView_seconds);
        lab_seconds.Text = (Int32.Parse(lab_seconds.Text) -1).ToString();
     });
}
```