# How to implement Timer Elapsed Event on UserInterface thread in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, timer, alert

Am implementing a System Timer on Xamarin Android and i have a problem with the elapsed event not raising a dialog box with the message "Time is up" when the countdown is Over...
I figured the problem might be not implementing the event on the User Interface thread so i need your help accomplishing that...
Here is my code for the Timer

```
    class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        int counter = 10;
        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        private int _countSeconds;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            //Trigger event every second
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            //count down 5 seconds
           

            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _countSeconds = 5;
  }
        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _countSeconds--;
            if (_countSeconds == 0) {
                _timer.Stop();
            Switch switch1 = this.FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.switch2);
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                Android.App.AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
                alert.SetTitle("");
                alert.SetMessage("Simple Alert");
                alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
                {
                    // Ok button click task  
                });
                switch1.Checked = false;
        }
```

I just want the Elapsed event handler to display an alert dialog box when the variable count down equals zero, Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592459/label-doesnt-update-on-older-system-version-xamarin/53592570#53592570

Comment: _timer.Start();

Comment: @Jonathana, Where does that code go?

Comment: @CodeTiger inside the `OnCreate()` method, after you initialized the instance of the timer you must call Start()...

Comment: @Jonathana, Cool

Comment: @jonathana _"Setting Enabled to true is the same as calling Start, while setting Enabled to false is the same as calling Stop."_ - [Timer.Enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.enabled?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: You should set `_countSeconds` _before_ `_timer.Enabled = true;`.

Comment: @Fildor, Thats why it was not working am still getting a ```Object reference not set to an instance of an object```

Comment: Find the stacktrace and look up in it, which line is causing it. Then you'll probably find, _what_ is null. Then fix that :)

Comment: @Fildor, is it because i have defined the Timer and made it private outside the ```oncreate``` method... here is the definition for the Timer which is in the class...```private System.Timers.Timer _timer;``` and the line that causes a null is ```_timer.Interval```

Comment: Private should be fine, since it's in the same class. Can you add the stacktrace to the question? That seems very unlikely since you just init that field in the line before ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221673/discussion-between-codetiger-and-fildor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first comment pointed me to a related question i found the method to implement the user thread and it now works as intended to display the alert dialog...

```
 private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
//This is how to make the Timer callback on the UI
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
            _countSeconds--;
                if (_countSeconds == 0)
                {
                    Switch switch1 = this.FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.switch2);
                    Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    Android.App.AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
                    alert.SetTitle("Its over");
                    alert.SetMessage("Simple Alert");
                    alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
                    {
                    // Ok button click task  
                });
                    alert.Show();
                    switch1.Checked = true;
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Cool Bro..Always happy to share